# How to import PBP Data from NFL.com into R

Tags: json, r, dataset

I am trying to import data from past NFL games in the form of Play-by-play tables and am mostly working in R to collect the data and create a data set.

An example of the data I am after is on this page: http://www.nfl.com/gamecenter/2012020500/2011/POST22/giants@patriots#menu=gameinfo&tab=analyze&analyze=playbyplay

I know that NFL.com uses JSON and much of the necessary data are in JSON files attached to the site.  My efforts at extracting data from these files using the JSON package in R have been pretty feeble.  Any advice y'all have is appreciated.

Would I just be better off using PHP to farm the data?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you have already succeeded loading the JSON files into R, but here is an example of that:

```
library(rjson)
json=fromJSON(file='http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/game-center/2012020500/2012020500_gtd.json')
json$`2012020500`$home$stats
```

If you are having trouble finding the URL of the JSON file, use Firebug (an extension for Firefox) and you can see the webpage requesting the JSON file.

The JSON file, is, of course, huge and complicated. But it is complicated data. Whatever you are looking for should be in there. If you are just looking for a straight dump of the play-by-play *text*, then you can use this URL:

http://www.nfl.com/widget/gc/2011/tabs/cat-post-playbyplay?gameId=2012020500

Answer (score 0):

I extracted all the data for one team for one season more-or-less manually.  If you want data for a lot of games consider emailing the league and asking for the files you mentioned.  They publish the data, so maybe they will give you the files.  The NFL spokesman is Greg Aiello.  I suspect you could find his email address with Google.

Sorry this is not a suggested programming solution.  If this answer is not appropriate for the forum please delete it.  It is my first posted answer.